# Equation involving absolute values

Tags: absolute-value

I am trying to solve this (knowing that $w$ is bigger than zero and real):

$$|1-\frac{7}{6}w-\sqrt{19}|=|1-\frac{7}{6}w+\sqrt{19}|$$

I put it into wolframalpha and it spat out $w = 6/7$, but how is that possible when the $w$-part is the same on each side??

Answer (score 4):

Interpret geometrically the absolute value of the difference: $\;\lvert x-a\rvert=\lvert x-b\rvert $ means $x$ is at the same distance from $a$ and $b$.

So precisely, it  is having the same $1-\dfrac76 w\;$ which makes the equation easy to solve: this expression is equidistant from $\sqrt{19}$ and $-\sqrt{19}$, i.e. is $0$.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align*}\left|1-\frac76w-\sqrt{19}\right|=\left|1-\frac76w-\sqrt{19}\right|&\iff\left(1-\frac76w-\sqrt{19}\right)^2=\left(1-\frac76w+\sqrt{19}\right)^2\\&\iff-2\left(1-\frac76w\right)\sqrt{19}=2\left(1-\frac76w\right)\sqrt{19}\\&\iff1-\frac76w=0\\&\iff w=\frac67.\end{align*}

Comment: THANK YOU! I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

Setting $$1-\frac{7}{6}w=a$$ then you have to solve
$$|a-\sqrt{19}|=|a+\sqrt{19}|$$
squaring this you will have
$$a^2-2\sqrt{19}a+19=a^2+2\sqrt{19}a+19$$ therefore $a=0$

Answer (score 0):

There are two possibilities
$$1-\frac{7}{6}w-\sqrt{19}=1-\frac{7}{6}w+\sqrt{19}\lor 1-\frac{7}{6}w-\sqrt{19}=-\left(1-\frac{7}{6}w+\sqrt{19}\right)$$
The first is impossible, the second gives
$$1-\frac{7}{6}w-\sqrt{19}=-1+\frac{7}{6}w-\sqrt{19}$$
that is
$$\frac{7}{3} w=2\rightarrow w=\frac{6}{7}$$
This is much simpler than squaring both sides...